# How to ask for user confirmation when submitting a form using FAPI

Tags: 6, forms

What I want is suppose a user enters same data twice in two rows then I want to show her an error/warning and now if she chooses to press submit again then I'd process and accept the form.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [confirm_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/6) function. See [Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/6#comment-5934) and [Here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/confirm_form/6#comment-8414) for examples

> This function returns a complete form array for confirming an action.
>   The form contains a confirm button as well as a cancellation link that
>   allows a user to abort the action.

Comment: In the second comment link there is a _submit handler in the bottom of the code: mymodule_form_submit. What I'm confused is after confirming it, again the else part of _submit handler is executed but how do I get the first form's form_state values? As all those I need them to save it in the database